What's the maximum sample rate for lattice wave filter?
From Wanhammar, Lars DSP Integrated Circuits:

EXAMPLE 6.5
The filter shown in Figure 6.30 has been implemented using so-called
redundant, bit-parallel arithmetic in which long carry propagations are avoided.
The results obtained [1999] using a 2-μm, double metal CMOS process were

Input data word length: 8 bits
Output data word length: 11 bits
Maximum sample rate: Approximately 35 MHz
Number of devices: Approximately 9000
Power consumption: 150 mW
Chip area: 14.7 mm² (including pads)



and before that

6.6.4 Maximum Sample Rate
[…]
The minimum sample period is also referred to as the iteration period bound. Loops that yield \$T_{min}\$ are called critical loops. This bound can directly be found from the signal-flow graph by inspection. The maximum sample rate can also be found from the intrinsic coefficient word length.

Does the filter in this example have a critical loop?
I think it does not have a critical loop as you can see from my sketch:

Update
Maybe this loop?

Update
3rd trial.


I’m voting to close this question because academic questions need an attempt at a solution.

@greybeard I don't think there is a loop in this filter. Can you show me the loop if you can find the loop?

@greybeard I have tried but there is no loop in this filter in my opinion

Trying is more important than success. Look at -input of #1, #2, #3, through the two Ts at the top.

@greybeard Take a look at my update. Is this correct?

@greybeard How about now? Why do you think your loop is the correct one for max sample rate?

I think this loop to be the relevant one because it is the only one I see.
